# Show that $G/2G \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2)^n$, where $G$ is an abelian group and $G \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-abelian-group

I tried to show this by constructing an explicit map as follows :

Since $G \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$, let $(m_1,\dots,m_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, where $m_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, is the image of $m \in G$. Define $\phi : G/2G \to (\mathbb{Z}/2)^n$ by setting
$$
\phi (m+2G) = ([m_1],\dots,[m_n]),\quad \text{where } [m_i] \in \mathbb{Z}/2.
$$
Is this correct ?. Seems like this is well-defined (not really sure). Since the author state this as "easy", i thought maybe there are any other simpler proof ? (maybe by first isomorphism theorem, etc). The statement above is in Lemma 9.18 of Lee's Topological Manifold 2nd ed. Thanks.

Comment: You did get the right function. Now just prove it's well defined, a homomorphism and a bijection.

Comment: You can use the homomorphism $G\longrightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$, $(m_1,\dots,m_n) \mapsto ([m_1],\dots, [m_n])$ and the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @Yanko : Thanks. Seems like its true.

Comment: @AlanMuniz : Set $f: G \to (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$. So $Ker\, f = \{e\}$ and $G/\{e\} = G \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2)^n $. Like that ?

Comment: Yes, but with the correct kernel $(2\mathbb{Z})^n$

Comment: @AlanMuniz : Sorry. Maybe this : $G/2G \cong \mathbb{Z}^n/2\mathbb{Z}^n \cong \mathbb{Z}^n/(2\mathbb{Z})^n \cong \mathbb{Z}^n/Ker\, f \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2)^n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been said, we can construct the homomorphism $f:G \to (\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^n$, $(m_1,\dots,m_n)\mapsto ([m_1],\dots,[m_n])$. Then $\ker(f)=2G$, so by the $1^\text{st}$ isomorphism theorem, $G/2G\cong (\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^n$